# Failed to check INSTALLED_APPS in django template

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to load some HTML element in my django template, if a specific app is defined in my settings.py file. But it doesn't work. The if statement behaves like the app doesn't exist:

```
            {% if 'myapp.edit_data' in INSTALLED_APPS %}
              <p> dfsdfsdf </p>
            {% endif %}
```

I also tried with other apps and I get the same behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you passed anything called INSTALLED_APPS to the template context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't automatically access settings like `INSTALLED_APPS` in the template. You have to add it to the template context.

For example, in the view, you could do:

```
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'INSTALLED_APPS': settings.INSTALLED_APPS})
```

If this check was in the base template, then you might want to create a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) instead of changing every view.